# Recommendation for a server side language (+ IDEs and Tools)

Tags: sql-server, web-services

- I want to create a server that queries another web service every 5 mins and stores the result in SQL database.
- I also want web functions exposed that run queries against the database.
- Im not expecting a huge amount of trafic and the code should not be too complex. It a small side project.

I do not know much abou servers, I have a little experience with .NET and MS SQL server, however I want something free (or al least cheap!)

What language should I use and what IDE's and tools might I find useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`ASP.Net`](http://www.asp.net/downloads), [`Visual Web Developer Express Edition`](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/), and [`Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition`](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/).  They are all powerful toolsets, and all free.  Also, SO has a lot of questions in .NET for dealing with web services and databases that you can reference as you are developing your project.